# Can not stop serving images as WebP on Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare

Storing my photos on AWS and serving them with Cloudflare.

Cloudflare serves all phtos as WebP. But some of browsers that don't support WebP, can not see my images. So that is a seriously problem for me.

Couldn find any configuration with that situation. How can I disable webp conversion? Or can I make It dynamically (firstly I define my visitor's browsers, then I show in WebP image, or not WebP image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least a couple settings that could affect this. They are under the "Speed" page on the "Optimization" tab of the Cloudflare Dashboard.

1. Image Resizing
2. Polish

Both these could be converting images to WebP format. However, in theory, they should only serve this format when the client / browser supports it.

You can turn off these settings and it should result in a quick fix, but I would also reach out to Cloudflare support with details on the clients you are seeing errors with.